# SQL Script in VM taking long time for execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have the Execute SQL Script package that contains the script to insert about 150K records.

Problem in here is when I execute the package in the Virtual machine its taking 25 min's approx and the same package in physical machine its taking 2 min's

Question 1? Why its taking that much time to load the same data in VM.
Question 2? How to solve this performance issue.

Physical machine configuration has 4GB Ram and 250GB HD + Windows server 2008 R2 + SQL server 2008 R2 Standard Edition.
Virtual machine has the same Configuration

**Update: The Problem is with the SQL Server in VM.**

**Question 1? Why its taking that much time to Run the same script in VM.**

**Question 2? How to solve this performance issue.**

Both the batabases schema in Physical Machine and VM are identical. Other databases are also same. There was no indexing applied for that tables in both machines. Datatypes are same. harddisk as I said has the same configuration.

No RAID is done on both the machines.

> Physical machine has the 2.67GHz RAM Quad Core and in the virtual machine has the
>   2.00GHz RAM Quad Core

Version of SQL PM:

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) Apr  2 2010 15:48:46    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Version of SQL PM:

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) Apr  2 2010 15:48:46    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

I executed the script Execution plan for both are the same as there is no difference in plan.

Vendor is HP ML350 Machine.

There are almost 20 VM's on the same physical server out of which 7 servers are active.

Comment: Is that the *only* thing the package does-a single execute sql task? Are the database structures identical? Run a schema compare between the two. How do data volumes compare between the two. What does the host look like? What does the disk io subsystem look like on both systems? Size matters not, iops is king

Comment: Also, check your statistics, fragmentation, etc on the slow system. Perhaps it's heavily fragmented. The quick test as to whether it's SSIS performing slowly on the VM or it's the VM's access to disk, assuming the package is only performing the Execute SQL Task, is to run that task in SSMS/sqlcmd/SQL Agent/.NET and see if times are comparable.

Comment: I Executed the same SQL Script in the SQL Server its taking the same time. Now the problem is with the SQL Script is taking time in the VM. What could be the reason.

Comment: Like billinkc said, are databases on physical macchine an VM identical? Do they have the same structure, same datatypes and same indexes? Are the harddisk in both machines identical? Does one or the other have RAID or SSD?

Comment: Please, provide some more information: `SELECT @@VERSION`, execution plans of the query from both physical and virtual machines, virtual machine of which vendor do you use?

Comment: How many other VMs are running on the physical server?  Its possible that there are too many VMs fighting for cpu cycles or network bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an article about properly setting SQL's configuration for a VM implementation here: [Best Practices for SQL Server](http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8964).  Below is an excerpt, though the article includes other tips and a good performance testing plan:

> Storage configuration problems are the number one cause of SQL  performance issues.  Usually these problems arise because the DBA  requests a virtual disk of the VI admin, the VI admin places the VMDK on  a LUN that may or may not meet the DBA's performance needs.  For  instance:
>
> 1. VMs' VMDK files placed on VMFS volumes without enough spindles.
> 2. Many VMDK files placed on a single VMFS volume which could use more spindles.
> 3. Database and log files placed on the same LUN which, you guessed it, could use more spindles.
>
> This may be obvious to some, but this problem occurs again and again.   The VI administrator should be aware of a few technical items that can  help understand and avoid this problem:
>
> 1. Based on the IO demands of the DB files, a certain number of 
>      spindles should be guaranteed to this file.  This means that its
>      VMDK  must be placed on a VMFS volume to accout for the SQL Server's
>      demands  and all of the other demands on that volume.
> 2. Mixing sequential activity (such as log file update) and random  activity
>      (such as database access) results in random behavior.  This  means
>      that the LUN configuration in the pre-virtual physical environment 
>      may not be sufficient for the consolidated environment.  This is 
>      discussed some in Storage Performance: VMFS and Protocols.
> 3. When storage isn't meeting the SQL Server's demands, the device  latency
>      or kernel latency (queueing time) will increase.  Read up on  these
>      counters in Storage Performance Analysis and Monitoring.

Comment: looks very complex. Can you tell me what to do exactly about storage configuration. Steps to solve this.

Comment: One of the major issues with sql on VM is i/o: if there are 10 virtual machines that need to read/write to the same disk, your i/o speeds will be 10x - 100x worse as everyone vies for the drive head's attention.  If you can dedicate an entire disk drive to your sql vm, you could see an dramatic performance improvement.  Also, don't allow all vm's access to all cores: that also slows things down with resource contention.  Instead, dedicate virtual cores to each vm.  Same with memory - one vm can steal it from another.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause for this problem is the lack of RAM. Having everything setup on a small 4GB RAM machine is your problem.

When you try to load those 150k rows into memory (remember, everything that happens in SSIS is in memory), a lot of those rows are being handled by your pagefile.

Pagefile on your VM is a lot slower than the one on your physical machine.

To solve this, increase the amount of RAM on your virtual machine.

Comment: I had increased the VM Size to 8GB. While I am running this task I check in the Resource manager of Task manager. There it has still about 2+GB free for any usage. I think this is not the Solution.

Comment: Anoter cause could be that the VM host (underlying machine) is busy. It does not always reflect in the VM...

Comment: I Noticed that the Physical machine has the 2.67 GHz RAM and in the virtual machine has the 2.00 GHz RAM. This may be the cause but I am not sure about it. I Restarted the machine so that all the services will be restarted and memory will be fresh. No other task is running in that machine.

Comment: No matter how you configure it, the VM will always be a subset of your physical machine and cannot outperform it. I will need more information on your end to help you. Start by giving us the SQL script. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem.

Two client machines (one physical, one virtual) execute a batch using SQLCMD. This batch calls a Stored procedure on a physical server (so it's not a memory problem since the elaboration is only on server side).

The batch executed from the physical machine takes 20 minutes. The batch executed from the virtual machine takes 1 hour and 20 minutes.

Using SQL profiler I noted that in the case of slow execution there is a wait type ASYNC_NETWORK_IO.

Probably the virtualized network layer is not optimized.

Could you run a SQL profiler and check if you see the wait type ASYNC_NETWORK_IO?

Comment: I checked with the SQL Profiler but there is no ASYNC_NETWORK_IO Wait. Even if the ASYNC_NETWORK_IO is the problem. What is the solution for that.